# Invalid character Exception when adding multiple parameters to NativeQuery

Tags: sql, jdbc

I use `JDBC` and want to create a `NativeQuery` with two parameters, one of them is a `String` and the other one is a `int`. When I try to do this like this:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
...
private final EntityManager entityManager;
....
String columnName = "exampleName";
int columnNumber = 5;
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.TCL_NUMBER from COL_NAME c where c.TABLE_NAME " +
                    "like ?1 and c.TCL_NUMBER like ?2;")
                .setParameter(1, columnName)
                .setParameter(2, columnNumber)
                .getSingleResult();
```

I get an `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character` Exception.
This is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE COL_NAME (
  TABLE_NAME               VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  TABLE_NUMBER             NUMBER(10,0)
);
```

Do I have to consider something special when I want to set an `int` as parameter?

Comment: Using a like clause on a number is not supported, AFAIK. A number is not a string.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. I'll check if this was the only problem tomorrow but I think so. If you like you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, you cannot append bind variables with indices (`?1`, `?2`, etc.). You need to use a simple question mark (`?`) for all variables, AFAIK. The indices of variables are implicitly assigned in the order they appear in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found out the problem in your query comes from the `?1` and `?2`. That will be compiled to something like:

```
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.TCL_NUMBER from COL_NAME c where c.TABLE_NAME like 'val1'1 and c.TCL_NUMBER like 'val2'2
```

Which is obviously incorrect sql syntax.

So the correct code would be:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.TCL_NUMBER from COL_NAME c where c.TABLE_NAME " +
                "like ? and c.TCL_NUMBER = ? ")
            .setParameter(1, columnName)
            .setParameter(2, columnNumber)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: @JB Nizet's comment is also valid -- you cannot compare numbers with `like`. If the intention is to match on a partial string for the `TABLE_NAME` column, the bind variable should be surrounded with wildcards, e.g. like this: `c.TABLE_NAME like '%' || ? || '%'` (the correct concatenation operator depends on the RDBMS vendor).

Comment: It's right that I have to remove the numbers after the `?`. It is also wrong to compare numbers with `like`, instead I have to do this: `... c.TCL_NUMBER = ?` as @JB Nizet mentioned.